# MacBook Air M1, external LG ultrawide thunderbolt monitor, Mac OS X Ventura

Tags: display, ventura

After Mac OS X Ventura upgrade I found that I did not like a default resolution of my Thunderbolt connected LG ultrawidescreen. It became not HiDPI anymore. So I started trying different resolutions and stuck in one low setting: now my mbair and LG switching between each other every few seconds not allowing me to interact ant change everything back.
Reinstalled OS X from recovery. Nothing has changed.
Hope there is something simple, but I’m too dumb to see it.
Please help me - have a lot to do remotely tomorrow…

Comment: Which exact LG model is this, and how they connected?

Comment: Have you tried restarting in Safe Mode and making changes?

Comment: Does disconnecting the LG allow you to get work done for now? Are you then able to freely change the MBA's built-in display resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you found it, but I saw a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daTWRlj4OZ4) where I think you hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while on the display settings' list of resolutions to access other resolutions not reported by the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Unplug the display from the power. Wait a minute. Plug it in again.